# Joomla 2.5 - fulltext in category blog layout

Tags: joomla-2.5, plugin

i modified blog_item.php to display fulltext in category blog layout. Works fine, but the content plugins are not rendered. They are rendered fine in introtext. Can anyone help me with the right code to be able to render the content plugins in fulltext?

```
// using this code to display fulltext
$itemID =  $this->item->id;
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "
SELECT `fulltext` 
FROM `#__content` 
WHERE `id` = $itemID;
";
$db->setQuery($query);
$fulltext = $db->loadResult();
```

I have found this piece of code to render the content plugins, but can't get it to work with fulltext:

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
PluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ('com_content.category', &$item, &$this->params, 0));
```

Comment: I don't understand why you modified the php file.  By not adding a readmore line, fulltext is displayed by default.  Were the content plugins not triggering?

Comment: I need 2 separate blocks of text for every entry in blog layout. I'm using introtext and fulltext separately. Content plugins works fine with introtext, but not with my fulltext modification.

Comment: Speaking from experience, rather than a core hack I'd probably write a custom CSS class that I apply via the editor dropdown (you're using JCE, right?) and that would have the same result as the single click to insert the readmore.

Comment: Agree with @Toni, there's no need to do this. Don't add a readmore and your fulltest *is* the introtext.

Comment: As you can read in the documentation here http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentPrepare, onContentPrepare needs the property "text" in your $item

Answer (score -3):

Don't edit the blog_item.php just create a template override.

this is how you get to render content plugin in content fulltext:

```
$full_text = JHTML::_('content.prepare', $fulltext);
// see it in var_dump($full_text);
```

**Note:**
You will get error if there are plugins that overriding your articles display, i.e : *DISQUS comment Plugin* by JoomlaWorks.
So you must edit(or override) that plugin views template instead. (not the blog_item.php).